# I need to remove the current selected image from an array of images

Tags: reactjs, arrays

So i put on a Json file with a lot of images. Now I take a randomized image from that list and display it. My goal is now, that I delete that currently displayed image, so I won't get it again when I press next.

This is a small part of the json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "image": "img/pics/1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "image": "img/pics/2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "image": "img/pics/3.png"
    }
]
```

```
import images from "../Index.json"


function Celeb() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState(images);

    const handleNext = () => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
      setImage(imageList[random].image);
      const unblurit = document.querySelector(".pic img");
      unblurit.classList.remove("unblur");
      unblurit.classList.add("blur");
      remove();
    }

    const remove = (id) => {
      const newList = imageList.filter(image => image.id !== id);
      setImageList(newList);
      console.log(imageList.length);
    }
}
```

So I am getting the json list and set it to ImageList. handleNext will give me a random img from that list and after that, I am calling the remove function. WIth console.log I wanna see, if that lenght of that array gets decreased by one, which is my goal because that current image on the display gets deleted after handleNext gets called

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you are trying is fine, you can also use `slice` method but still you will be on page one, what happens is that once you change or get a new array in `newList` const and call `setImageList` it considers the array unchanged because it does not deep check the value, you should use a spread operator

```
setImageList([...newList])
```

This will consider the changes as a new array and set your list, your `remove` method will be

```
const remove = (id) => {
  const newList = imageList.filter(image => image.id !== id);
  setImageList([...newList]);
  console.log(imageList.length);
}
```

Though, your console log will not work inside the method, as setState is an async call which will return a promise but the console.log that you have placed inside the remove method will print a value before the state is updated.

[Here's](https://playcode.io/1034819) a small playcode demo for you to test things out